# Trait bounds on references for local variables

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have a zero-copy implementation of an operation:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'b Key> for &'a Key {
    type Output = Key;

    fn add(self, rhs: &'b Key) -> Key {
        // ... calculate sum from given references ...
        Key::new(sum)
    }
}
```

I have several structs with similar properties that all implement `Add` with two references as input, returning a new value, i.e. `&'a T: Add<&'b T, Output = T>`

I'd like to write a generic function that can make use of any of these implementations, but nothing seems to satisfy the borrow checker:

```rust
pub struct FixedSet<T> {
    items: Vec<Option<T>>,
}

impl<T: Clone + PartialEq> FixedSet<T> {
...
    pub fn sum<'a>(&self) -> Option<T>
        where
            T: 'a,
            &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output=T>,
    {
        if self.items.len() == 0 {
            return None
        }
        let mut iter = self.items.iter(); //** Error **
        let mut sum = iter.next().unwrap().as_ref().unwrap().clone();
        for v in iter {
            let t = v.as_ref().unwrap();
            sum = &sum + t; // *A*
        }
        Some(sum)
    }
```

The error is: `error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements`.

I'd *like* to tell the compiler, "Hey, when calling `add` with two references to `T`, don't worry, the references only need to live until the return from `add` at **A**"; but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, `Key` is undefined. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: `pub fn sum(&self) -> Option<T> where for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>`

Comment: Your function body can also be `self.items.iter().map(|i| i.as_ref().unwrap()).fold(None, |acc, i| { acc.map_or(Some(i.clone()), |acc| Some(&acc + i)) })`; although I'm not a fan of the `unwrap`s.

Comment: Or `let mut iter = self.items.iter().map(|v| v.as_ref().unwrap()); iter.next().map(|init| iter.fold(init.clone(), |acc, i| &acc + i))`

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster; I was looking for the HRTB stuff, but didn't know what to look for. Since this question is in fact a dupe, I'll just close it.

Comment: If you couldn't find those existing answers in your search, then leaving this question as a signpost to them would help someone who searched for the same query strings (which presumably you used when asking your question).